Explain this call in Bootstrap 5 documentation
In the Bootstrap Tooltip documentation it gives this sample code to initialize all tooltips in page:
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})

What is the reason to use [].slice.call()?
Cannot document.querySelectorAll() be called directly?

Here [].slice.call creates an array of the NodeList returned by querySelectorAll.

Cannot document.querySelectorAll() be called directly? You can't iterate over the NodeList that querySelectorAll() returns, so it needs to be converted to an array, which is what that code does. A more modern and simpler ay is to use the spread selector [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')].
